# Dynamically refer to an image in OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

In OpenOffice.org Writer I have a drawing with a caption that I would like to reference dynamically by its associated number.

For example: An image has the caption "Drawings `1.3` some text".
In another part of the document, I want to refer to the image by writing "On drawing `1.3` we can see..."

I want this reference to be dynamic. I don't know if I'm going to add more drawings before or after that one, and if I did, it would change its number.

How can I reference such a link to an image so that I don't have to manually update and fix all references to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already assigned a caption to the image, you can just refer to it using a cross-reference. Just put the cursor to where the cross-ref should appear in your text, and select menu `Insert -> Cross-reference...`. In the dialogue that opens, make sure to select "`Illustration`" as Type.

Now, a list of images should appear on the right, together with a list of reference options. You can reference the page, the caption, the number and so on.

[image: cross-ref options]

As result, openoffice will insert a field that will get updated by default if the number or the caption of the image changes.